# How many graphs are there on $n$ vertices that every pair of vertices has $X$ common neighbours?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What I can see is that there can be two cases where X=1:

- (Triangle Free) A strong regular graph where all vertices share one common neighbours.
- (Friendship Graph) A strong regular graph where $\lambda=1$ and $\mu=1$.

I would like to know how we would count the number of graphs when $X$ could be anything or when we are dealing with random graphs.